# Basic c# if-statement inquiry

Tags: c#, if-statement

I need to input 3 numbers, and then output the highest & lowest of the 3 numbers using IF commands. I have everything working, except I'm getting 1 largest number (correct) and 3 outputs of the lowest number (incorrect). Now I totally understand *why* they're all being displayed, I just do not know how to fix it. My code, once the integers have been defined by user input, is as follows:

```
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Largest Number: " + num1);
}

if (num2 > num3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number: " + num3);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number: " + num2);
}
```

and then duplicated 3 times, switching the respective integers. I understand what the issue is, it's that the second if command is correct for all 3 scenarios. I just... don't know how to fix it. I feel like I just need to join these two if statements together somehow but I'm unsure how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Learn to use debugger, put break point on if statements and see how the control is going to other conditions and if there is anything **else** you need.

Comment: Did you try to move the second `if` (the one testing for the smallest number) block into the first (the one testing for the largest number) ?

Comment: Not really sure about the downvotes, this could be a basic question for others, but it is not that bad of a question to get downvotes.

Comment: If statements can be nested look into that.

Comment: Note  that you're going to want to use >= instead of > in case any of the numbers are equal.

Comment: Not sure how to respond directly to a comment as I'm new to this site, but Sidewinder94's response was exactly what I was missing. I have no idea how I was so oblivious to this as it makes so much sense in hindsight. Thanks for all the responses guys. I have a long, long journey to go!

Comment: @Madrical Thanks, though the best answer technically speaking, was Steve's one.

Comment: What if num1 is not the largest number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, and you will have to, on many instances nest blocks.
This way, the second if will only be evaluated if the first was evaluated as true.

```
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Largest Number: " + num1);

    if (num2 > num3)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number: " + num3);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number: " + num2);
    }
}
```

This is only to answer your most immediate problem, that is, the smallest number being displayed more than one time.

You might encounter others, for example, as others mentioned : What if two numbers are equals ?

Comment: what if `num1` is the smallest ? you will get no output.

Comment: Thanks man, this is exactly what I was missing. To this downvoting, keep in mind the code is duplicated twice to cater for num1, num2 or num3 being the largest. I've tested all 3 scenarios and it works.

Comment: this is true dont know why people are downvoting all the answers

Comment: @Habib read the question, this block is repeated three times in th OP's code, with all the permutations, it is not the complete solution, just a nesting example

Comment: @Sidewinder94, you are right, I missed "and then duplicated 3 times, switching the respective integers.". Removed my downvote, +1

Answer (score 2):

To get the largest/lowest the best way is to have a variable to store the current max/min instead of checking every cases (permutation).

Something like

```
    int largest = int.MinValue;
    int smallest = int.MaxValue;

    if (num1 > largest)
        largest = num1;
    if (num2 > largest)
        largest = num2;
    if (num3 > largest)
        largest = num3;

    if (num1 < smallest)
        smallest = num1;
    if (num2 < smallest)
        smallest = num2;
    if (num3 < smallest)
        smallest = num3;

//output largest/smallest
```

Comment: This is the only answer so far that doesn't produce multiple output if two of the values are equal

Answer (score -1):

No `if` statements necessary:

```
Console.WriteLine("Largest Number: " + Math.Max(Math.Max(num1, num2), num3));
Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number: " + Math.Min(Math.Min(num1, num2), num3));
```

Comment: its clear that the OP is trying to learn about how to use if statement

Comment: The question literally says they want to do it with if statements.